# Cómo solucionar Error 500 en el comando rollback de PHP App Engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine

Dejo una captura del error:

```
Mac-mini-de-roberto:competicionmental vernetit$ appcfg.py rollback /Users/vernetit/competicionmental
10:16 AM Application: competicionmental
10:16 AM Host: appengine.google.com
10:16 AM Rolling back the update.

Error 500: --- begin server output ---

<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>500 Server Error</title>
</head>
<body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>
<h1>Error: Server Error</h1>
<h2>The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.<p>Please try again in 30 seconds.</h2>
<h2></h2>
</body></html>
```

Vi que hubo un error así en el legunaje de python en 2015 que se reconoció oficialmente y fue solucionado con el tiempo, pero ya pasaron 12 hs. Alguien sabe como proceder en esta situación?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema se arreglo luego de 4 días sin que yo cambie ninguna configuración aparentemente solucionado por parte del de App-engine